# Custom user fields in Devise 3 under Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4, attr-accessible, strong-parameters

I'm using the release candidate of Devise 3 so that I can use it with Rails 4. In Rails 3.2 I used to be able to add a custom field to my `User` model by simply adding that field to the registration/edit.html.erb and registration/new.html.erb files (after running the proper migration). Then I'd just add that field to the `attr_accessible` list of fields in the model.

However, in Rails 4, there is no `attr_accessible` list and I can't simply add fields in the views. How do I add custom User fields?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was told to look in the main [README on the github page and there it was](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters). Easy.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :username
  end
end
```

Answer (score 9):

Adding

```
     def configure_permitted_parameters
         devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email) }
         devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation) }
         devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password) }
     end
```

To applicationcontroller worked for me.

Comment: You might also need: `before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?`

Answer (score 3):

In case you want to permit additional parameters you can do with a simple before filter in your

> ApplicationController:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :username
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable Strong Parameters for devise instead of attr_accessible for doing that you need to create new initializer like:

```
DeviseController.class_eval do
  def resource_params
    unless params[resource_name].blank?
      params.require(resource_name).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me)
    end
  end
end
```

Make sure that you cloned gem from rails4 branch(plataformatec/devise). 
Remove attr_accesible from model

Comment: for strong parameter configuration follow this guide https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters